# Angular 8 - 404 Not Found Instantiating http://localhost:4200/rxjs/operators

Tags: angular, rxjs

**I am getting an error while running an app which was migrated from 6 to 8 recently and using rxjs/operators . if I do not use any operators with rxjs, it works fine..**

*ERROR Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Fetch error: 404 Not Found
  Instantiating http://localhost:4200/rxjs/operators
  Loading http://localhost:4200/assets/bulletin.umd.js*

Loading assets/bulletin.umd.js

*Error: Fetch error: 404 Not Found*

```
at system.src.js:1512

at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:391)

at Object.onInvoke (core.js:26256)

at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invoke (zone.js:390)

at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.run (zone.js:150)

at zone.js:910

at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)

at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:26247)

at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)

at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)

at resolvePromise (zone.js:852)

at resolvePromise (zone.js:809)

at zone.js:913

at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:423)

at Object.onInvokeTask (core.js:26247)

at ZoneDelegate.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.ZoneDelegate.invokeTask (zone.js:422)

at Zone.push../node_modules/zone.js/dist/zone.js.Zone.runTask (zone.js:195)

at drainMicroTaskQueue (zone.js:601)
```

defaultErrorLogger @ core.js:4002

package.json

"dependencies": {

```
"@angular/animations": "^8.2.4",

"@angular/cdk": "~8.2.3",

"@angular/common": "^8.2.4",

"@angular/compiler": "^8.2.4",

"@angular/core": "^8.2.4",

"@angular/forms": "^8.2.4",

"@angular/http": "^7.1.0",

"@angular/material": "^8.2.3",

"@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.4",

"@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.4",

"@angular/router": "^8.2.4",

"@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "^5.1.0",

"@ngui/auto-complete": "^2.0.0",

"@swimlane/ngx-datatable": "^15.0.0",

"angular2-busy": "^2.0.4",

"angular2-signaturepad": "^2.9.0",

"angular2-text-mask": "^9.0.0",


"core-js": "^2.5.7",

"font-awesome": "^4.7.0",

"hammerjs": "^2.0.8",

"jquery": "^3.2.1",

"moment": "^2.22.2",

"ng-busy": "^6.1.1",

"ngx-pagination": "^3.1.1",

"rxjs": "~6.5.4",

"rxjs-compat": "^6.3.2",

"systemjs": "^0.21.4",

"zone.js": "~0.9.1"
```

},

"devDependencies": {

```
"@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.17",

"@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "^0.803.2",

"@angular/cli": "^8.3.2",

"@angular/compiler": "^8.2.4",

"@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.4",

"@angular/language-service": "^8.2.4",

"@types/jasmine": "~3.4.4",

"@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3",

"@types/jquery": "^3.2.16",

"@types/node": "~12.12.3",

"codelyzer": "~5.2.0",

"jasmine-core": "~3.5.0",

"jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",

"karma": "~4.4.1",

"karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",

"karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~2.1.0",

"karma-jasmine": "~2.0.1",

"karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.3.1",

"ng-packagr": "^5.5.0",

"ts-node": "~8.4.1",

"tsickle": "^0.37.0",

"tslib": "^1.9.0",

"tslint": "~5.9.1",

"typescript": "3.5.3",

"webpack": "4.39.3"
```

}

component

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs';
import {debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged, map, filter} from 'rxjs/operators';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-typahead',
  templateUrl: './typahead.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./typahead.component.css']
})
export class TypaheadComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  public model: State;

  formatter = (state: State) => state.name;

  search = (text$: Observable<string>) => text$.pipe(
    debounceTime(200),
    distinctUntilChanged(),
    filter(term => term.length >= 2),
    map(term => states.filter(state => new RegExp(term, 'mi').test(state.name)).slice(0, 10))
  )

}
```

App compiles fine and only getting error when actually running the app. Any clues what is wrong here..

If I do not use any rxjs operators and app works fine. error is coming on using any rxjs operators.. filter/debounsTime/switchMap/mergeMap etc..

Comment: If you uninstall rxjs-compat, does it change anything?

Comment: We could not uninstall as it has dependencies on lots of other shared library modules which has old code prior to angular 8..